# Can I port my old save game to Wasteland 2 Director's Cut?

Tags: steam, wasteland-2, wasteland-2-directors-cut

I started playing Wasteland 2 a while back and only recently noticed the Director's Cut. On Steam, it's listed as a separate game, so I installed it. When I launched it, I noticed that it didn't show my existing save game from original edition.

Is there any way to port my save game or do I have to start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoot. I just dug up a FAQ from the release of the Director's Cut. They say, "no".

> **Will save files or characters transfer over from the original game?**
>
> No. The number of changes to the game in the Director's Cut means it's more or less impossible for us to guarantee compatibility. Save file formats have changed on a technical level and old saves may not be read correctly in the Director's Cut, and the gameplay changes mean that characters made on the old version of the game would not play well in the Director's Cut.

Comment: The game makers must have made some SERIOUS overhaul to make their save games not work with the new game.  You can look forward to the improvements.  If you think about it this is pretty major and should be a much better experience.